# Get Google Drive Link in Google Sheets if the folder name matches

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-drive-shared-drive

I'm trying to find a script that can retrieve the folder link (of Google Drive) in Google Sheets when the folder name matches.
Below is the code which I used but it is only showing the first 2 drive links and after that, it is showing the error "Cannot retrieve the next object: iterator has reached the end"

```
function onOpen() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var menu = [{name: "Get Folder Links", functionName: "getFolderLinks"}];
  sheet.addMenu("Custom Menu", menu);
}

function getFolderLinks() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 3;
  var data = sheet.getRange(startRow, 7, sheet.getLastRow() - startRow + 1, 1).getValues();
  
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var folderName = data[i][0];
    var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(folderName).next();
    var link = folder.getUrl();
    sheet.getRange(i+startRow, 15).setValue(link);
    logger.log(query);
  }
}
```

Folder Names are in Column G3:G and the link to the folder will be shown in O3:O.

Need advice from community experts on the above code.

P.S: Can the code work on a real-time basis (without clicking on the button which is created by the above code) and without any limitations?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

> Cannot retrieve the next object: iterator has reached the end

This error means the folder does not exist when you call `next()`.

I've modified your script to check if a folder exists:

```
function getFolderLinks() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 3;
  var data = sheet.getRange(startRow, 7, sheet.getLastRow() - startRow + 1, 1).getValues();
  
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var folderName = data[i][0];
    Logger.log(folderName);
    var folderIterator = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(folderName);
    if(folderIterator.hasNext()) //check if the folder exists
    {
        var link = folderIterator.next().getUrl();
        sheet.getRange(i+startRow, 15).setValue(link);
    } else 
    {
      Logger.log("Folder not exist: " + folderName);
    }
  }
}
```

> Can the code work on a real-time basis (without clicking on the button which is created by the above code) and without any limitations

To achieve this, you can schedule a Time-Driven trigger shown in the below picture:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Charles for your response. Is there any other alternative instead of time driven or should I go for a manual button? Secondly, I'm getting a new error "Exception: Cannot call SpreadsheetApp.newMenu() from this context." All the names which are in Google Sheets are available in Google Drive

Comment: For the error, did you select `getFolderLinks` in the `choose which function to run` dropdown list?

Comment: In your original question, what do you mean by running this in `real-time`? Do you mean when there is a new record, you want to trigger the code?

Comment: as and when a new entry is made the link of the folder should appear

Comment: I clicked on the button again and no error was shown but a few rows were empty. Is it feasible to get the link of the complete folder links and have it in a different spread sheet and do a vlookup to match ?